# Printing binary without trailing 0s?

Tags: python

Trying to create a small program that takes in positive integers and converts it into reverse binary.

I've gotten this far:

```
import math
integer = int(input())

while integer > 0:
    x = integer % 2
    print(int(math.floor(x)), end='')
    integer = integer / 2
```

The problem with this is that the output would have unnecessary trailing 0s. For example, if the input is 12, the output would be 0011000......

I've tried the **int** function to remove floats, I also tried **floor** function to round up(albeit I might've done it wrong).

Could the problem be a lack of sentinel value?

Comment: `integer // 2` [is your friend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlADJpNtS_s&t=8s)

Comment: or `integer >> 1`

Comment: Or even `bin(integer)[2:][::-1]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The underlying problem is that "removing" floats in the ways that you describe doesn't address the problem. The `integer` variable is a floating-point value, because of `integer = integer / 2`. Please see the linked duplicate to understand the problem and the normal solution (which is as simple as using `//` instead).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have reversed a binary number like this:

```
def reverse_bits(n):
    res = 0
    for i in range(n.bit_length(), -1, -1):
        if n & (1 << i):
            res += 1 << (n.bit_length() - i)
    return res

bin(reverse_bits(12))  # '0b110'
```

You can bit shift to the right, until there is a 1 in the rightmost bit, to remove trailing zeros:

```
def remove_trailing_zeros(n):
    while not n & 1:
        n = n >> 1
    return n
```

All together:

```
bin(remove_trailing_zeros(reverse_bits(12)))
Out[11]: '0b11'
```

Comment: Not sure what this dude wants, but I'm pretty sure it's not to print the binary representation of 'the input divided by the largest power of 2 which divides it'. Sounds like he's aiming at printing the binary representation of the input in reversed order (at least according to the example in the question).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I was a bit confused by his question, i added how to reverse a binary number with the addition of removing the trailing zeros

Answer (score -1):

use `//` instead of `/` in division

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternate approach:

```
integer = 3
print (bin(integer)[2:][::-1])
```